# AngularFire2 - Setting custom key when pushing

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

I am learning angularfire2 in Ionic2

```
 const newUser = this._db.list('/users');
  setTimeout(() => {
    newUser.push(this.userInfo)
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
  },3000)
```

I want to know if there is any way I can set my custom key when pushing new data. I tried various suggestion given on internet to update the key after insert, but no success.

Comment: I think you can do this by using the update() function instead of the push function. You have to get a reference that includes your custom key: this._db.ref('/users/<yourCustomKey>').update({data:'your Data here'});

Comment: So, first I have to push the data, and on its success I need to update the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than `.push`, I tried `.set`

```
const userList = this._angualrFireDB.list('/users');
userList.set(this.userAuthData.uid,
  {
    name: 'Ashwin',
    age: 38,
    dob: '10/11/1978',
    uid: this.userAuthData.uid
  });
```

This works, and I am getting my uid as my new key.

Comment: is this RealTime DB or FireStore?

Answer (score 0):

You can use update instead of push

```
this.afoDatabase.object ('/Users/' + <custom key>).update (user);
```